# Adding a meta question to main site favorites

Tags: support, bookmarks

I wish to add the MathJax page:

- [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

to my favorites on my main home page, but clicking favorites only adds it to my meta home page. Is this impossible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "favorites" are listed per-site, and meta.math.SE is technically a different site than math.SE. You could always just add a link to that page in your "about me".

Comment: Would bookmarking the page in your browser do the trick?

Comment: @GerryMyerson; no it wouldn't - it has to be in favorites on my main page

Comment: So, what the advantage of having it a favorite, as opposed to having it as a bookmark? Either way, it's a couple of clicks away, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Probably the fact that favorites show updates?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Excellent argumentation. I'm sold.

Comment: i've added it to bookmarks toolbar, so its only 1 click away. thanks for all your help

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, this is impossible. Favorites are marked per-site. The meta site is in fact a separate site, with some loose connection to main on the level of reputation and navigation.

Comment: could the page in question be posted on the main site say as a community wiki?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I would be very against doing that.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry But then if one makes a change, it would have to be changed in main site as well. So that is more work.